# Query files from SQL database and display the result as Windows Search

Tags: windows-7, windows-search, sql, c#

Warning: novice programmer here. I got SQL database with file paths based on different criteria stored in it. And I want to display the files associated with the desired criteria as a Windows Search result. Any guidelines on how to achieve this ? I'm programming in C#.

I believe there is something useful here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff628790(v=vs.85).aspx It's just that I can't quite understand. Thanks in advance for the time.

Comment: @JulianKnight Please refrain from suggestion they ask on another SE site. Please use the close/off topic feature to get it migrated. This avoids double posting and confusion.

Comment: @CharlieRB. I have voted. However, there is nothing worse than voting questions closed without telling the OP (and the world in general) WHY. Otherwise people cannot easily learn how to improve questions. I should have said that I'd voted but new users find the structure and rules of SE very difficult and complex to comprehend (well I did anyway!).

Comment: Agreed, it can be difficult to understand. I made the same mistake. And, yes, we do need to make an effort to help them understand.

Answer (score 1):

You are really looking for extensions to Windows search:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725753%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Or looking at trying to federate Windows Search with another, external service - in this case a SQL database.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd940456%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I'm afraid that neither of these is a simple task and will require significant Windows system and programming skills.

The most common way of doing this integration is to do it the other way round. Call out to the Windows Search Index from MS SQL Server. Of course, you would need your own search front-end then as well.